# How to implement an js animation into Wordpress homepage

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I would like to implement this code https://codepen.io/giulianomlodi/pen/GaNOQp into my wordpress websiste. Right now I can't even let it appear when I create separate css and js files on the same folder and link them to an html page to display it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./particle.css">

</head>

<!-- particles.js container --> 
<body>



    <!-- particles.js lib - https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js --> 
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./particle.js"> </script>





</body>
```

Nothing appear when I try to visualize the html page on the browser.

I can't understand how to make it work. The final aim is to display it on the homepage of my website https://www.babbasons.com/ instead of the actual video animation.

Is there someone who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add the div tag for the particle.js to know where to render elements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./particle.css">
</head>

<!-- particles.js container --> 
<body>
    <div id="particles-js"></div>
    <!-- particles.js lib - https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js --> 
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./particle.js"> </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
particlesJS("particles-js", {
    "particles": {
        "number": {
            "value": 80,
            "density": {
                "enable": true,
                "value_area": 800
            }
        },
        "color": {
            "value": "#ffffff"
        },
        "shape": {
            "type": "circle",
            "stroke": {
                "width": 0,
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            "polygon": {
                "nb_sides": 5
            },
            "image": {
                "src": "img/github.svg",
                "width": 100,
                "height": 100
            }
        },
        "opacity": {
            "value": 0.5,
            "random": false,
            "anim": {
                "enable": false,
                "speed": 1,
                "opacity_min": 0.1,
                "sync": false
            }
        },
        "size": {
            "value": 3,
            "random": true,
            "anim": {
                "enable": false,
                "speed": 40,
                "size_min": 0.1,
                "sync": false
            }
        },
        "line_linked": {
            "enable": true,
            "distance": 150,
            "color": "#ffffff",
            "opacity": 0.4,
            "width": 1
        },
        "move": {
            "enable": true,
            "speed": 6,
            "direction": "none",
            "random": false,
            "straight": false,
            "out_mode": "out",
            "bounce": false,
            "attract": {
                "enable": false,
                "rotateX": 600,
                "rotateY": 1200
            }
        }
    },
    "interactivity": {
        "detect_on": "canvas",
        "events": {
            "onhover": {
                "enable": true,
                "mode": "repulse"
            },
            "onclick": {
                "enable": true,
                "mode": "push"
            },
            "resize": true
        },
        "modes": {
            "grab": {
                "distance": 400,
                "line_linked": {
                    "opacity": 1
                }
            },
            "bubble": {
                "distance": 400,
                "size": 40,
                "duration": 2,
                "opacity": 8,
                "speed": 3
            },
            "repulse": {
                "distance": 200,
                "duration": 0.4
            },
            "push": {
                "particles_nb": 4
            },
            "remove": {
                "particles_nb": 2
            }
        }
    },
    "retina_detect": true
});
var count_particles, stats, update;
stats = new Stats;
stats.setMode(0);
stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
stats.domElement.style.left = '0px';
stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
document.body.appendChild(stats.domElement);
count_particles = document.querySelector('.js-count-particles');
update = function() {
    stats.begin();
    stats.end();
    if (window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles && window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles.array) {
        count_particles.innerText = window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles.array.length;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
};
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```css
canvas {
 display: block;
 vertical-align: bottom;
}


/* ---- particles.js container ---- */

#particles-js {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #dd8d3a;
 background-image: url("");
 background-repeat: repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: 50% 50%;
}


/* ---- stats.js ---- */

.count-particles {
 background: #000022;
 position: absolute;
 top: 48px;
 left: 0;
 width: 80px;
 color: #13E8E9;
 font-size: .8em;
 text-align: left;
 text-indent: 4px;
 line-height: 14px;
 padding-bottom: 2px;
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.js-count-particles {
 font-size: 1.1em;
}

#stats,
.count-particles {
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-left: 5px;
}

#stats {
 border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.count-particles {
 border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>


<div id="particles-js"></div>
```

**Bellow code put in your theme functions.php**

```
function testtheme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'particles-js', wp_enqueue_script( 'particles-js', 'http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js',array( 'jquery' ), '20181224',true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'testtheme_scripts' );
```

open your theme Style and put css code in style.css 
open your theme script file and put js code in your script file

Comment: Hi and thank you!

I get this error when I put the given code on the funcion php of the theme 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'add_action' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in /web/htdocs/www.babbasons.com/home/wp-content/themes/jupiter/functions.php on line 453

What's my mistake ?

Comment: @akademeia copy my functions.php latest code and check your curly brackets

Comment: I can't make it works... I putted the code just after another function...

it looks like this 


 /**
  * Add tour list then include main Tour class.
  *
  * @since 5.9.6
  */
 private function tour() {

  // Add tour list. Choose short, one-word id.
  add_filter( 'mk_tour_list', function( $tour_list ) {
   $tour_list = array(
    'intro' => array(
     'state' => true,
    ),
   );

   return $tour_list;
  } );

  include_once THEME_ADMIN . '/tour/class-mk-tour.php';
 }

Comment: /**
  * Add Particles
  */
 function testtheme_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'particles-js', wp_enqueue_script( 'particles-js', 'http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js',array( 'jquery' ), '20181224',true );
 }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'testtheme_scripts' );

 
 

}

Comment: @akademeia remove last } curly brackets

Comment: function testtheme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'particles-js', wp_enqueue_script( 'particles-js', 'http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js',array( 'jquery' ), '20181224',true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'testtheme_scripts' );

copy above function

Comment: @akademeia got it ?

Comment: line  478  wp-content/themes/jupiter/functions.php. 

syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: I just pasted the function at the end of the file

Comment: function testtheme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'particles-js', wp_enqueue_script( 'particles-js', 'http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js',array( 'jquery' ), '20181224',true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'testtheme_scripts' );

Comment: @akademeia paste above my comment in your function file thanks